# Origen de la locución "de cuajo"

Tags: adverbios, locuciones

La palabra *[cuajo](https://dle.rae.es/cuajo)* significa, según el diccionario:

> 1. m. Fermento de la mucosa del estómago de los mamíferos en el período de lactancia, que coagula la caseína de la leche.
> 2. m. Efecto de **cuajar<sup>2</sup>**.
> 3. m. Sustancia con que se cuaja un líquido.
> 4. m. **cuajar<sup>1</sup>**.
> 5. m. coloq. Calma, pachorra.

De aquí, las acepciones de *[cuajar](https://dle.rae.es/cuajar)* a las que se hace referencia son:

> 1. tr. Transformar una sustancia líquida, especialmente si contiene albúmina, como la leche o el huevo, en una masa sólida y pastosa.
> 2. tr. Recargar de adornos algo.

La acepción de "calma, pachorra" ya daría para una pregunta, pero en este caso me gustaría preguntar cómo se llegó desde las acepciones de *cuajo* y *cuajar* mencionadas, a lo siguiente:

> **de cuajo**
>
> 1. loc. adv. De raíz, sacando enteramente algo del lugar en que estaba arraigado. *Arrancó el árbol de cuajo.*

¿Qué tienen que ver los fermentos o el recargar algo de adornos con el hecho de extraer algo completamente?

Expresión además harto antigua, por lo que veo:

> *Aberruncare verbo actiuo es arrincar o sacar de cuaio.*
>
> Alfonso de Palencia, "Universal vocabulario en latín y en romance", 1490 (España).

Comment: A mí me suena algo de una hierba que se llama así.

Comment: Por lo menos en italiano hay unas hierbas que se llaman ["caglio"](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/caglio). La traducción de "cuajo" al italiano es precisamente "caglio".

Comment: En esta página puede encontrarse información que parece pertinente (si tengo tiempo, la transcribo como respuesta): http://etimologias.dechile.net/?descuajar

Answer (score 2):

Según [Léxico](https://www.lexico.com/es/definicion/cuajo) el origen de **cuajo** viene de:

> Voz patrimonial del latín **coagulum**, derivado de ( co- ‘juntamente’ ) y
> agere ‘empujar’, ‘hacer mover’. Del mismo origen que coágulo (V.), se
> ha mantenido, especialmente para referirse a la leche como ocurre con
> el étimo latino. A la misma familia etimológica pertenecen cuajar
> (nombre) y cuajar (verbo).

Esto pudiera indicar que hace referencia a empujar conjuntamente, a mover conjuntamente, por lo tanto, a mover todo de un lado a otro, a desplazarlo enteramente. De ahí lo de arrancar de cuajo: mover, quitar todo de un lado.

Otra idea sería la de arrancar las malas hierbas, ya que hay que quitarlas de raíz para que no vuelvan a crecer. Una de dichas malas hierbas pudiera ser la **hierba de cuajo** ([Cynara cardunculus o cardo](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cynara_cardunculus)).

Al arrancar "de cuajo", quitas la hierba de cuajo, es decir, de raíz.